# Run uiautomator in Runtime.getRuntime().exec() does not give real time status

Tags: android, runtime.exec, android-uiautomator

In my uiautomator script, i will send some interim status. When i run the uiautomator from command prompt using adb, i can see my status print outs one at a time. But when i run it with code snippet as below, i dont get it one at a time. I will only get the whole big chunk of status all at once after the test finish. I need to get the status in real time manner for some parsing.

It looks to me like the output is buffered and flushed at once. I've tried to change the buffer size of the BufferedReader but still not working as how it looks like when running from command prompt.

Anyone has any idea?

```
String tempString;
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uiautomator runtest DummyUiAutomation.jar -c com.dummy.DummyAutomation#DummyAction");
BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
while ((tempString = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
     //do some parsing
}
```

Comment: You are trying to run this in from your app?

Comment: yes. u can ignore the concern regarding superuser or rooting the device. its not a prob in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [Process.waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) after reading the stream?

```
String tempString;
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uiautomator runtest DummyUiAutomation.jar -c com.dummy.DummyAutomation#DummyAction");
BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
while ((tempString = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
     //do some parsing
}
process.waitFor();
```

From docs:

> Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process
>   represented by this Process object has terminated. This method returns
>   immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. If the
>   subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread will be blocked
>   until the subprocess exits.